# tomcat8 - custom error page for 400

Tags: tomcat, nginx, error-handling, web.xml

In Tomcat (v8.5.24) an URL with a query parameter containing an unencode curly brace ("{") produces a 400 error.

You can configure Tomcat to allow it with "relaxedQueryChars". But this is not what I want. I tried to write a custom error page and add it to web.xml

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/error/error400</location>
</error-page>
```

But this does not work as Tomcat is really killing the request and does not process the error pages (org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor:737)

It seems there is no way to handle it. Now I tried to handle it in nginx. But to handle it there I need to set "proxy_intercept_errors = on" and I don't want to intercept all error codes from my proxy.

So no luck rendering a custom 400 page in this scenario? Or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced to this issue and as a workaround I implemented own ErrorReportValve by extending org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve class and configured it on my Tomcat.

To accomplish this the following article was really helpful: http://robupcraft.com/tomcat-valves/

Note that for the implementation (and successful build), you need tomcat-catalina dependency.